# Numpy module not found error vs code & jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy

unable to import numpy into my vs code project due to following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

I have already installed numpy with the following results:

`sudo -H pip3 install -U numpy`

`Successfully installed numpy-1.19.0`

However, when I check for numpy installation with following command:

```
   >>> import numpy

   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have also tried to change the environment in VS code from 3.8.3 64-bit to 3.7.6 54-bit ('base':conda) but didn't get any better results.

FYI, numpy is currently installed in my home directory as well as

Is it because I have 4 different version (Python 2.7.17 64-bit, Python 3.6.9 64-bit, Python 3.7.6 64-bit & 3.8.3 64-bit) of Python installed on my Linux Mint Cinnamon OS?

Also when I run `echo $PATH` command, I get following (spectre - userName):

```
/home/spectre/anaconda3/bin:/home/spectre/anaconda3/condabin:/home/spectre/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Don't know if it is correct.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue with numpy installation.

The issue was with my python version 3.7 which was nested in anaconda directory and not at its default place.

I uninstalled the anaconda using the following command:

```
$ conda install anaconda-clean
$ anaconda-clean -yes
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3
$ rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
```

Updated with alternatives command:

```
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

Now to list all the alternative installation:

`$ update-alternatives --list python`

and finally for the option to swap between different Python versions:

`$ update-alternatives --config python`

Selected the correct option for python 3.8 from the given prompt and done.

Installed numpy:

```
$ pip3 install numpy
$ pip3 install --upgrade numpy
```

Now all issues with numpy resolved.